# Migrating data from de-activated app to new app

Tags: django, django-south

I'm replacing an old Django app with a new one and because both use UserManager(), which seems to clash if you have two apps doing that, I considered simply disabling the old app and adding the new. However, I have no idea how I would access the old data for a proper datamigration. I could use db.execute() to execute SQL, but I have no way of checking the results? I'd like to do things like 'if table x exists, get the data from there and create new objects as so for the new app'. Any hints?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258130/how-do-i-migrate-a-model-out-of-one-django-app-and-into-a-new-one and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498163/move-django-model-from-one-app-to-another can help.

Comment: Thanks, but that only works if you keep the old app activated as well. I need to deactivate it, otherwise I get clashes.