# Django 1.7 makemigrations renaming tables to None

Tags: python, django-1.7, django-migrations

I had to move a few models from one app to another, and I followed the instructions on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26472482/188614.
Basically I used the `CreateModel` migrations generated by `python manage.py makemigrations`, wrapped them inside `state_operations`, and added the `'db_table'` meta option with the old table's name.
Everything works fine, the models on the `new_app` are corretly using the old tables.
But if I run `python manage.py makemigrations new_app` it creates an `AlterModelTable` migration for each table renaming them as `None`, like this:

```
migrations.AlterModelTable(
    name='cidade',
    table=None,
),
```

Is this a bug, or expected behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

I just had this problem myself.

The answer you were following includes this in the migration in `new_app`:

```
options={
    'db_table': 'newapp_themodel',
},
```

This options dict should reflect the values set by the `Meta` class on your model. In my case, I was not setting `db_table` in Meta, but had blindly copied the options code.

You need to update the options in your migration for `newapp` to either remove the `db_table` value if you don't set it in `Meta` or to match the value you set in `Meta`.