# Move models between Django (1.8) apps with required ForeignKey references

Tags: python, database, django-models, schema-migration

This is an extension to this question: [How to move a model between two Django apps (Django 1.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648393/how-to-move-a-model-between-two-django-apps-django-1-7/26472482#26472482)

I need to move a bunch of models from `old_app` to `new_app`. The best answer seems to be [Ozan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648393/how-to-move-a-model-between-two-django-apps-django-1-7/26472482#26472482), but with required foreign key references, things are bit trickier. @halfnibble presents a solution in the comments to Ozan's answer, but I'm still having trouble with the precise order of steps (e.g. when do I copy the models over to `new_app`, when do I delete the models from `old_app`, which migrations will sit in `old_app.migrations` vs. `new_app.migrations`, etc.)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Migrating a model between apps.**

The short answer is, *don't do it!!*

But that answer rarely works in the real world of living projects and production databases. Therefore, I have created a [sample GitHub repo](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory) to demonstrate this rather complicated process.

I am using MySQL. *(No, those aren't my real credentials).*

**The Problem**

The example I'm using is a factory project with a **cars** app that initially has a `Car` model and a `Tires` model.

```
factory
  |_ cars
    |_ Car
    |_ Tires
```

The `Car` model has a ForeignKey relationship with `Tires`. (As in, you specify the tires via the car model).

However, we soon realize that `Tires` is going to be a large model with its own views, etc., and therefore we want it in its own app. The desired structure is therefore:

```
factory
  |_ cars
    |_ Car
  |_ tires
    |_ Tires
```

And we need to keep the ForeignKey relationship between `Car` and `Tires` because too much depends on preserving the data.

**The Solution**

**Step 1.** Setup initial app with bad design.

Browse through the code of [step 1.](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/tree/step1)

**Step 2.** Create an admin interface and add a bunch of data containing ForeignKey relationships.

View [step 2.](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/tree/step2)

**Step 3.** Decide to move the `Tires` model to its own app. Meticulously cut and paste code into the new tires app. Make sure you update the `Car` model to point to the new `tires.Tires` model.

Then run `./manage.py makemigrations` and backup the database somewhere (just in case this fails horribly).

Finally, run `./manage.py migrate` and see the error message of doom,

**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1217, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails')**

View code and migrations so far in [step 3.](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/tree/step3)

**Step 4.** The tricky part. The auto-generated migration fails to see that you've merely copied a model to a different app. So, we have to do some things to remedy this.

You can follow along and view the final migrations with comments in [step 4.](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/tree/step4) I did test this to verify it works.

First, we are going to work on `cars`. You have to make a new, empty migration. This migration actually needs to run before the most recently created migration (the one that failed to execute). Therefore, I renumbered the migration I created and changed the dependencies to run my custom migration first and then the last auto-generated migration for the `cars` app.

You can create an empty migration with:

```
./manage.py makemigrations --empty cars
```

**Step 4.a.** Make custom *old_app* migration.

In this first custom migration, I'm only going to perform a "database_operations" migration. Django gives you the option to split "state" and "database" operations. You can see how this is done by viewing the [code here](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/blob/step4/cars/migrations/0002_auto_20150603_0642.py).

My goal in this first step is to rename the database tables from `oldapp_model` to `newapp_model` without messing with Django's state. You have to figure out what Django would have named your database table based on the app name and model name.

Now you are ready to modify the initial `tires` migration.

**Step 4.b.** Modify *new_app* initial migration

The operations are fine, but we only want to modify the "state" and not the database. Why? Because we are keeping the database tables from the `cars` app. Also, you need to make sure that the previously made custom migration is a dependency of this migration. See the tires [migration file](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/blob/step4/tires/migrations/0001_initial.py).

So, now we have renamed `cars.Tires` to `tires.Tires` in the database, and changed the Django state to recognize the `tires.Tires` table.

**Step 4.c.** Modify *old_app* last auto-generated migration.

Going *back* to cars, we need to modify that last auto-generated migration. It should require our first custom cars migration, and the initial tires migration (that we just modified).

Here we should leave the `AlterField` operations because the `Car` model *is pointing* to a different model (even though it has the same data). However, we need to remove the lines of migration concerning `DeleteModel` because the `cars.Tires` model no longer exists. It has fully converted into `tires.Tires`. View [this migration](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/blob/step4/cars/migrations/0003_auto_20150603_0630.py).

**Step 4.d.** Clean up stale model in *old_app*.

Last but not least, you need to make a final custom migration in the cars app. Here, we will do a "state" operation only to delete the `cars.Tires` model. It is state-only because the database table for `cars.Tires` has already been renamed. This [last migration](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/blob/step4/cars/migrations/0004_auto_20150603_0701.py) cleans up the remaining Django state.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having trouble moving models with ForeignKey relationships to each other. That is, I have models `A` and `B` in  `old_app` that have a ForeignKey relationship between each other and I want to move both models to `new_app`. If I copy the models to `new_app` (so they still remain in `old_app`) and run make migrations I get a `Reverse accessor clashes` error. However, if I instead cut and paste the models from `old_app` to `new_app` and then run make migrations, I get an error in one of `old_app`'s old migrations since `A` and `B` don't exist anymore in `old_app`. Any insight?

Comment: You are going to have to cut and paste the models over to `new_app`, but leave the migrations in `old_app`. First, you will need to create a custom migration in `old_app`, similar to Step 4.a. to rename both database tables to the `new_app` naming scheme. Moving two inter-dependent apps simultaneously may have slightly different migration flows than the one above, but with enough espresso, it should be possible.

Comment: The basic steps will be the same. 1. Create a migration that renames database tables. 2. Create a state-only migration that sets up the models in the new app. 3. Modify the auto-generated AlterField migration that is created by django when updating all model code references. (The main thing is to remove any "DeleteModel" lines). And 4., Create a final state-only migration to remove the ghost models from `old_app`.

Comment: Thanks @halfnibble this was perfect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm ;) Just one little suggestion: be more explicit when you say "[I changed the number](https://github.com/halfnibble/factory/blob/d4db34aa98a7ed141026de4b3fad9910f64f3854/cars/migrations/0003_auto_20150603_0630.py#L10)". Maybe "swap the migration file name" or something like this...

Comment: Question: Assuming developer's interest and time, are there any technical design reasons preventing this from becoming a standard feature of Django's migrations mechanism?

Comment: @Teekin I cannot think of any technical reasons. Although to reduce possible ambiguity, I think it would be best to make a management command. Perhaps `manage.py migrate --refactor cars.Tires > tires.Tires` or something like that. I'd do it myself if I had time, but I gotta work for a living. :)

Comment: Generic Foreign Keys will still break! You'll also need to add a migration to rename the `app_label` in `django_contenttypes` to reflect the change.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I noticed the number of steps can be reduced. After updating the migrations for the `RenameModelTable` (old app) and `CreateModel` (new app), you can generate the final migration with `manage.py migrate`. It can update the foreignkeys and state in a single migration.

Comment: This was great, thanks a ton. Saved me big time.  This also works (with minor adjustments) if you have model A and B in one app, with model C in another, and C is related to B and you want to move B into it's own 3rd app

Comment: If anyone used this and has trouble with migrations saying that a relation "xxx_yyy" does not exist. What I had to do was making sure that the migration, that does `AlterModelTable`, had dependencies on the latest migration in all the apps that referenced the old model by foreign key or other relation

Comment: I also need to remove the old app. But if I do, there will be conflicts since the migrations are interdependent. Is there any way to delete the old app?

Comment: Still works like a charm 5 years on (Django 1.11). I moved 6 models all linked with FKs and M2Ms very smoothly with this after trying and failing with previous methods. Thank you especially for the useful git repo

Comment: @vdboor, about the reduced steps you spoke of, are you saying that in order to generate the final migration steps, we can delete the last file that would have been generated via makemigrations (instead of altering it), then do a migration to rename the tables only, then do another makemigration to regenerate the last migration file that should be correct?

Comment: @Mike anything you didn't share yet with others can be reverted, or removed/merged together. There is no problem in manually editing the migration files - just as long as you first revert any local change and don't push changes to others.

Comment: Thanks @vdboor, thanks but that's not what I'm asking (I'm aware files can be changed manually and like the idea). I was wondering if the steps I described were correctly summarizing more specifically what you were saying was your simpler solution?

Answer (score 4):

Just now moved two models from `old_app` to `new_app`, but the FK references were in some models from `app_x` and `app_y`, instead of models from `old_app`.

In this case, follow the steps provided by Nostalg.io like this:

- Move the models from `old_app` to `new_app`, then update the `import` statements across the code base.
- `makemigrations`.
- Follow Step 4.a. But use `AlterModelTable` for all moved models. Two for me.
- Follow Step 4.b. as is.
- Follow Step 4.c. But also, for each app that has a newly generated migration file, manually edit them, so you migrate the `state_operations` instead.
- Follow Step 4.d But use `DeleteModel` for all moved models.

Notes:

- All the edited auto-generated migration files from other apps have a dependency on the custom migration file from `old_app` where `AlterModelTable` is used to rename the table(s). (created in Step 4.a.)
- In my case, I had to remove the auto-generated migration file from `old_app` because I didn't have any `AlterField` operations, only `DeleteModel` and `RemoveField` operations. Or keep it with empty `operations = []`
- To avoid migration exceptions when creating the test DB from scratch, make sure the custom migration from `old_app` created at Step 4.a. has all previous migration dependencies from other apps.

  ```
  old_app
    0020_auto_others
    0021_custom_rename_models.py
      dependencies:
        ('old_app', '0020_auto_others'),
        ('app_x', '0002_auto_20170608_1452'),
        ('app_y', '0005_auto_20170608_1452'),
        ('new_app', '0001_initial'),
    0022_auto_maybe_empty_operations.py
      dependencies:
        ('old_app', '0021_custom_rename_models'),
    0023_custom_clean_models.py
      dependencies:
        ('old_app', '0022_auto_maybe_empty_operations'),
  app_x
    0001_initial.py
    0002_auto_20170608_1452.py
    0003_update_fk_state_operations.py
      dependencies
        ('app_x', '0002_auto_20170608_1452'),
        ('old_app', '0021_custom_rename_models'),
  app_y
    0004_auto_others_that_could_use_old_refs.py
    0005_auto_20170608_1452.py
    0006_update_fk_state_operations.py
      dependencies
        ('app_y', '0005_auto_20170608_1452'),
        ('old_app', '0021_custom_rename_models'),
  ```

BTW: There is an open ticket about this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24686

Comment: I should have read your comment, before trying @Nostalg.io s approach, because I ran into all of those problems you solved ;) Still thanks for documenting it here! However this complex procedure is hard to get by just reading and I think I actually had to try it to understand it. I needed my database backup a couple of times, so it's really the most important part to have a working backup first!

Comment: Well I hope it helped :) Indeed moving models across apps is cumbersome. In a world where things change constantly (evolutionary design) I think we really need to find a better way of doing this.

Maybe a good idea is to start with loose FKs right from the start, preparing for a microservice architecture in the future. I agree you're not going to fully benefit from the full ORM power, but still it's a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to move the model and you don't have access to the app anymore (or you don't want the access), you can create a new Operation and consider to create a new model only if the migrated model does not exist.

In this example I am passing 'MyModel' from old_app to myapp.

```
class MigrateOrCreateTable(migrations.CreateModel):
    def __init__(self, source_table, dst_table, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MigrateOrCreateTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.source_table = source_table
        self.dst_table = dst_table

    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        table_exists = self.source_table in schema_editor.connection.introspection.table_names()
        if table_exists:
            with schema_editor.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("RENAME TABLE {} TO {};".format(self.source_table, self.dst_table))
        else:
            return super(MigrateOrCreateTable, self).database_forwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0002_some_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        MigrateOrCreateTable(
            source_table='old_app_mymodel',
            dst_table='myapp_mymodel',
            name='MyModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=18))
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've built a management command to do just that - move a model from one Django app to another - based on nostalgic.io's suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30613732/1639699

You can find it on GitHub at [alexei/django-move-model](https://github.com/alexei/django-move-model)

Comment: hello, does this fix GenericForeign Key?

Comment: @injaon I does create migrations for related models. I hadn't test it with generic FKs, but you're free to open an issue on GitHub about that

Answer (score 2):

You can do this relatively straightforwardly, but you need to follow these steps, which are summarized from a question in the [Django Users' Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-users/Matthew$20Pava%7Csort:date/django-users/M1WYXDNtNEs/OkAvqCybBQAJ).

1. Before moving your model to the new app, which we will call `new`, add the `db_table` option to the current model's `Meta` class. We will call the model that you want to move `M`. But you can do multiple models at once if you want to.

   ```
   class M(models.Model):
       a = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       b = models.IntegerField()

       class Meta:
           db_table = "new_M"
   ```
2. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`. This generates a new migration file that will rename the table in the database from `current_M` to `new_M`. We will refer to this migration file as `x` later on.
3. Now move the models to your `new` app. Remove the reference to `db_table` because Django will automatically put it in the table called `new_M`.
4. Make the new migrations. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`. This will generate ***two*** new migrations files in our example. The first one will be in the `new` app. Verify that in the dependencies property, Django has listed `x` from the previous migrations file. The second one will be in the `current` app. Now wrap the operations list in both migrations files in a call to `SeparateDatabaseAndState` to be like so:

   ```
   operations = [
       SeparateDatabaseAndState([], [
           migrations.CreateModel(...), ...
       ]),
   ]
   ```
5. Run `python manage.py migrate`. You are done. The time to do this is relatively fast because unlike some answers, you're not copying records from one table to the other. You are just renaming tables, which is a fast operation by itself.

Answer (score 1):

After work was done I tried to make new migration. But I facing with following error:

`ValueError: Unhandled pending operations for models:
  oldapp.modelname (referred to by fields: oldapp.HistoricalProductModelName.model_ref_obj)`

If your Django model using `HistoricalRecords` field don't forget add additinal models/tables while following @Nostalg.io answer.

Add following item to `database_operations` at the first step (4.a):

```
    migrations.AlterModelTable('historicalmodelname', 'newapp_historicalmodelname'),
```

and add additional Delete into `state_operations` at the last step (4.d):

```
    migrations.DeleteModel(name='HistoricalModleName'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Nostalg.io's way worked in forwards (auto-generating all other apps FKs referencing it). But i needed also backwards. For this, the backward AlterTable has to happen before any FKs are backwarded (in original it would happen after that).  So for this, i split the AlterTable in to 2 separate AlterTableF and AlterTableR, each working only in one direction, then using forward one instead of the original in first custom migration, and reverse one in the last cars migration (both happen in cars app). Something like this:

```
#cars/migrations/0002...py :

class AlterModelTableF( migrations.AlterModelTable):
    def database_backwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        print( 'nothing back on', app_label, self.name, self.table)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):                                                         
    dependencies = [
        ('cars', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    database_operations= [
        AlterModelTableF( 'tires', 'tires_tires' ),
        ]
    operations = [
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState( database_operations= database_operations)         
    ]           


#cars/migrations/0004...py :

class AlterModelTableR( migrations.AlterModelTable):
    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        print( 'nothing forw on', app_label, self.name, self.table)
    def database_backwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        super().database_forwards( app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('cars', '0003_auto_20150603_0630'),
    ]

    # This needs to be a state-only operation because the database model was renamed, and no longer exists according to Django.
    state_operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Tires',
        ),
    ]

    database_operations= [
        AlterModelTableR( 'tires', 'tires_tires' ),
        ]
    operations = [
        # After this state operation, the Django DB state should match the actual database structure.
       migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState( state_operations=state_operations,
         database_operations=database_operations)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but I'm sure I'll hear why it's a terrible idea. Add this function and an operation that calls it to your old_app migration:

```
def migrate_model(apps, schema_editor):
    old_model = apps.get_model('old_app', 'MovingModel')
    new_model = apps.get_model('new_app', 'MovingModel')
    for mod in old_model.objects.all():
        mod.__class__ = new_model
        mod.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('new_app', '0006_auto_20171027_0213'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(migrate_model),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='MovingModel',
        ),
    ]
```

Step 1: backup your database!
Make sure your new_app migration is run first, and/or a requirement of the old_app migration. Decline deleting the stale content type until you've completed the old_app migration.

after Django 1.9 you may want to step thru a bit more carefully:
Migration1: Create new table
Migration2: Populate table
Migration3: Alter fields on other tables
Migration4: Delete old table

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this after a couple of months (after successfully implementing Lucianovici's approach), It seems to me that it becomes *much* simpler if you take care to point `db_table` to the old table (if you only care about the code organisation and don't mind outdated names in the database).

- You won't need AlterModelTable migrations, so there's no need for the custom first step.
- You still need to change the models and relations without touching the database.

So what I did was just take the automatic migrations from Django and wrap them into migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState.

Note (again) that this only could work if you took care to point db_table to the *old* table for each model.

I'm not sure if something is wrong with this that I don't see yet, but it seemed to have worked on my devel system (which I took care to backup, of course). All data looks intact. I'll take a closer look to check if any problems come up...

Maybe it's also possible to later rename the database tables as well in a separate step, making this whole process less complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Coming this is one a little late but if you want the **easiest path** AND don't care too much about preserving your migration history. The simple solution is just to wipe migrations and refresh.

I had a rather complicated app and after trying the above solutions without success for hours, I realized that I could just do.

```
rm cars/migrations/*
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Presto! The migration history is still in Git if I need it. And since this is essentially a no-op, rolling back wasn't a concern.