# Move models between Django (1.8) apps with ForeignKey references

Tags: django, migration

I basically have the same question [Move models between Django (1.8) apps with required ForeignKey references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601107/move-models-between-django-1-8-apps-with-required-foreignkey-references). The response from @halfnibble
seems valid but in my case there is a ForeignKey pointing from new_app to old_app.
I wil translate my names to names on @halfnibble example for simplicity, Tires will have a ForeignKey to Car.

The migrations runs fine.
Few migrations later I rename old_app.Car to old_app.NewCar (I don't know if this affects).
But some migrations later when I try to delete new_app.Tires and in next migration old_app.NewCar I get the error:

```
>python manage.py migrate
  ....
ValueError: Unhandled pending operations for models:
  old_app.newcar (referred to by fields: new_app.Tires.car)
```

If I run my apps tests they run correctly, I have also inspected generated MySQL queries and seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, I left this information in case anybody has the same problem.

The problem was really induced by the rename of old_app.Car to old_app.NewCar.

makemigrations detected the change and created two migrations one in old_app with the rename and other on new_app updating the ForeingKey. The problem was that you have to manually add in new_app dependencies the old_app migration where the model was renamed.