# What is a "state operation" and "database operation" in SeparateDatabaseAndState?

Tags: django

This is an extension to this question: [Move models between Django (1.8) apps with required ForeignKey references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601107/move-models-between-django-1-8-apps-with-required-foreignkey-references)

The Nostalg.io's answer worked perfectly. But I still can't get what is a "**state operation**" and "**database operation**" and what actually is going on when using **SeparateDatabaseAndState**.

Answer (score 17):

A bit tough topic and not enough clear explanations out there, so here are my 50 cents.

It's all about **state** of your application models. What's a state? Imagine you have an app with a model MyModel and some migrations:

```
# app/migrations/
    # 001.py
        CreateModel(name='MyModel')
    # 002.py
        AddField(name='total', field=models.IntegerField)
    # 003.py
        RemoveField(name='total', field=models.IntegerField)
```

When you call `manage.py makemigrations app`, Django looks through all changes in `app/migrations/001.py...003.py` to get what's expected to be in your model - i.e. the state of the model. So, state is roughly a combined result of your migrations. If it differs from what you have in your `MyModel` class in `app/models.py`, `makemigrations` creates new migration with corresponding change. Like if `MyModel` class currently has `total` field, while in last migration it was removed, Django creates a migration with `AddField()` operation. Unlike what people often think, `makemigrations` does NOT look at actual database table.

Normal migration operation changes both state and database: `CreateModel()` tells Django "hey Django, this migration adds new table" and performs "CREATE TABLE" on the database.

`SeparateDatabaseAndState` is needed when you need to do different things to  the state and to the database (or may be you need to modify just one of them).

Let's look at example from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/writing-migrations/#changing-a-manytomanyfield-to-use-a-through-model), where they change existing ManyToMany relation to "through" model. They had model Author and model Book with M-M relation:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

But now you want to have a through-model `AuthorBook` - optionally with some extra fields in it:

```
class AuthorBook(models.Model):
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through=AuthorBook)
```

But you don't want new table - you want to use existing `core_book_authors` table which Django created automatically, and you want data in it.
So you create a migration with `SeparateDatabaseAndState` operation with `database_operations` and `state_operations`.

```
operations = [
    migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
        database_operations=[
            migrations.RunSQL(
                sql='ALTER TABLE core_book_authors RENAME TO core_authorbook',
                reverse_sql='ALTER TABLE core_authorbook RENAME TO core_book_authors',
            ),
        ],
        state_operations=[
            migrations.CreateModel(name='AuthorBook'),
        ]
    ),
]
```

In `database_operations` they rename existing M-M table according to new model name. That's the only thing you actually need to do with the database, unless you're adding new field to `AuthorBook` at the same time.

`state_operations` with `CreateModel()` tells Django: "this migration adds new table" (actually it does not - as we know from `database_operations`, it renames existing table). But because of this `state_operations` our new model gets into the state and Django knows this model is "created" and will not try to create it on next `makemigrations` call.

So, in `SeparateDatabaseAndState` operation, `database_operations` affect the database and not the state, `state_operations` affect the state and not the database.