# How do I migrate models between apps in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-apps

I am trying to migrate models between apps following Ozan’s answer here: [How to move a model between two Django apps (Django 1.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648393/how-to-move-a-model-between-two-django-apps-django-1-7)

However, I get stuck when I try to run `python manage.py makemigrations new_app`. I get this error message:

```
The field products.Offer.compared_image was 
declared with a lazy reference to 'products.comparedimagepair', 
but app 'products' doesn't provide model 'comparedimagepair'.
```

How do I avoid this? What is causing this? I updated the reference but it seems to still be failing

Comment: Can you show us the models? Right now it seems you have a relation to one model that doesn't exists in your app