# How do I merge a Django app?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-migrations

I have two Django apps. `A`, the core app, and `B`, which started out as an individual app, but actually fits better within `A` as we later discovered. I'm able to move all the code from `B` into `A`, but falling short when it comes to the database.

`B` will be deleted, so it'd be best if the migration lived entirely in `A`. That way, anyone can pull the latest code and run `manage.py migrate` and it will work on local machines even after `B` is deleted.

However, the data still needs to be migrated from `B` to `A` when running the migration on the production database.

#### My attempts

I tried inlining `B`'s models in the migration, querying them (if they exist), then saving new objects using the new models. This is a technique I've used with SQLAlchemy before. The only problem is that Django then adds these temporary models to `django_contenttype` and tells me "The following content types are stale and need to be deleted" the next time I run a migration. (I also don't know if Django does anything else I might have missed.)

I also tried setting `db_table` to the old app's database table [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498163/move-django-model-from-one-app-to-another), but then the table doesn't exist when running locally from scratch. If I include a `CreateModel` migration, then I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "b_model" already exists` when migrating on an *existing* database.

Any ideas?

Comment: The linked question is marked as a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258130/how-do-i-migrate-a-model-out-of-one-django-app-and-into-a-new-one. Seems to have a more robust way of solving this problem.