# Django move table to other app using db_table and don't delete original table

Tags: python, django, models, schema-migration

I have moved my table from `app_a` to other `app_b` using [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table). I initially added meta information as,

```
# app_b.models.ppy
class Table(models.Model)
# all fields
class Meta:
    db_table = 'app_a_table'
    app_label = 'app_a'
```

If I make any changes in this table in `app_b`, migrations is not generating new migration file under migration folder.
It says.

```
No changes detected in app 'app_b'
```

I tried from this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498163/move-django-model-from-one-app-to-another), and commented `app_label = 'app_a'`. Now after migration it detects the changes and create the migration file.

Then I execute `python manage.py migrate` command, it is constantly asking to delete original table `app_a_table`.

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    app_a | table

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: no
```

How do I suppress this notification? How do I tell django migration that this table exists in different app?

Comment: You should create a mirgation, that creates a new table. copies the data and deletes the old one. Don't forget the references.

Comment: @KlausD. if the table is large that would lead considerable down time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I moved my table from `app_a` to other `app_b` using `db_table` and `app_label`.
Migrations are working if I run them only for `app_a`.

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_a
```

This command run migration for `app_b`